# using resolve in angularjs routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on angularjs app and my config looks like this:

```
.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider, $localStorage){
  $stateProvider
  .state('Login',{
    url:'/login',
    templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
    controller:'LoginCtrl',
    resolve: {
    /*   if($localStorage.userInfo === null || $localStorage.userInfo === undefined){
          }else{
           $scope.signInUser();
  }*/
    }
  })
```

My `login.html` looks like this:

```
<form name="loginform"></form>
```

I want that if $localstorage.userInfo exists, do not show login.html but call $scope.signInUser function else show the form.

How do I do this using resolve of the route? Can I please get some directions?

I have tried easier ways but I ended up with 10 digest cycles reached error so I was adviced to use resolve for the purpose.

My complete route looks like this:

```
.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider, $localStorage){
  $stateProvider
  .state('Login',{
    url:'/login',
    templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
    controller:'LoginCtrl',
    resolve: {
       if($localStorage.userInfo === null || $localStorage.userInfo === undefined){
          }else{
           $scope.signInUser();
  }
    }
  })

  .state('Deployment',{
    url:'/deployment',
    templateUrl:'templates/deployment.html'
  })
  .state('Bill',{
    url:'/bills',
    templateUrl:'templates/bills.html'
  })
//$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector) {
           var $state = $injector.get('$state');
            $state.go('Login');
        });
```

Comment: If the only requirement is to 'show' the form or not, why don't you use a directive that handles this? Will be much easier instead of resolving this on every route change.

Comment: It's not  just about showig the form. It's about showing it if $localstorage.userinfo is not available and if available, redirecting to state to Deployment using state.go after calilng signInUser function. With directive I ended up with 10 digest cycles reached error and this is why I am trying to do it here in resolve which shall be called only once in any case. @skubski

Comment: Try by using ``return $q.reject({ redirect: 'state.b' });``   as mentioned in https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/898

Comment: @SameerK: Could you please make it a bit more specific to my problem? I am yet to figure out how do I integrate it in here

Comment: But you don't want to restrict any of the other pages? @Simran Kaur?

Comment: That's right,It's just about skipping login state if we have the credentials and jumping on to deployment after calling signInUser function and if we do not have the credentials, just go to login state

Comment: @SameerK: It gives me $q. reject is not a function

Answer (score 0):

How I achieved this

routes.js

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $location) {
    $routeProvider.when("/home", angularAMD.route({
        templateUrl: "templates/pages/home.html",
        controller: "HomeController",
        controllerUrl: "app/controllers/home_controller",
        resolve: {
            weekendTypes: function(WeekendTypes) {
                return WeekendTypes.getAll()
            }
        }
    }));
}]);
```

factory.js

```
app.factory("WeekendTypes", ["$http", function($http) {
    return {
        getAll: function() {
            var _apiurl = config_data.GENERAL_CONFIG.AJAX_URL + "weekend/getAll",
                promise = $http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: _apiurl
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    return data
                });
            return promise
        }
    }
}])
```

You should use something like this

```
getData: function(){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $timeout(function(){
     var data=localStorageService.get('description'),
     deferred.resolve(data);
   },3000);
   return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer what I had asked at all. I know the basic use of resolve but your answer is not specific to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Had to try it by myself before sharing code.

Remove the `resolve` function from set local storage value as data like below

```
state('Login',{
   url:'/login',
   templateUrl:'templates/login.html',
   controller:'LoginCtrl',
   data : {userIfno : $localStorage.userInfo}
  })
```

Then make use of `.run` function like

```
.run($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(toState) {
        if (toState.data.userIfno === '') {
            $state.go('Login', {}); //here set proper state
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: It does redirect to Login state when localstorage does not have userinfo but it wont redirect to deployment when it does not. Besides, if I was to redirect it to deployment from run block, I can not call $scope.signInUser which is what I need to do

Comment: What ``$scope.signInUser`` function does ?? i assume that it logs in users. right ??

Comment: call an api and changes the state to deployment

Comment: yes, definitely logs in , retrieve results from a get api and then changes state

Comment: How about get rid of $scope.signInUser from this .config file and move it place which will be called once user submit login form after entering username and pwd. It will do the same job as its doing now , i.e logs user , store the userinfo in localstorage and change the state. Once the state changes to deployment, then above posted code will check if user logged in or not. move data : {userIfno : $localStorage.userInfo} to deployment state.